# How can I get values of Apache configuration variables like FcgidMaxRequestLen?

Tags: php, apache, apache-modules

In a PHP code I need get the values of Apache's mod_fcgid conf variables like:

- FcgidMaxRequestLen
- FcgidBusyScanInterval
- FcgidAuthenticator

(Full list at http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html)

Is there a way I can get those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of getting Apache configuration directives through the PHP API, other than what's exposed by PHP itself. You would have to parse the Apache config files.

This is not trivial however, if you consider things like conditional settings and inclusion of multiple config files. It may also include security issues such as accidentally revealing config settings that can compromise your server.